# get week start and end date from week number & year in android

Tags: android, calendar

I wish to get the start date & end date of the week, for a week number passed in to the method. For example, if i pass the week number as `51` and the year as `2011`, it should return me start date as `18 Dec 2011` and the end date as `24 Dec 2011`

Are there any methods that will help me achieve this?

Comment: I tried using MonthDisplayHelper & JodaTime, but somehow was not able to achieve the required. Thanx Sunil & Chase.. will try ur solution &  let u know

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following method to get first date and end date of a week

```
 void getStartEndOFWeek(int enterWeek, int enterYear){
//enterWeek is week number
//enterYear is year
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, enterWeek);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, enterYear);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMM yyyy"); // PST`
        Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
        String startDateInStr = formatter.format(startDate);
        System.out.println("...date..."+startDateInStr);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Date enddate = calendar.getTime();
        String endDaString = formatter.format(enddate);
        System.out.println("...date..."+endDaString);
    }
```

Comment: year of 2015, 2016 come one week more but 2013,2014 come exactly... is this the issue of leap year..

Comment: Hi Kamal, any solution for above mentioned issue??

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `java.util.Calendar` class. You can set the year with `Calendar.YEAR` and the week of year with `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` using the `public void set(int field, int value)` method.

As long as the locale is set properly, you can even use `setFirstDayOfWeek` to change the first day of the week. The date represented by your calendar instance will be your start date. Simply add 6 days for your end date.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
// Clear the calendar since the default is the current time
calendar.clear(); 
// Directly set year and week of year
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 51);
// Start date for the week
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
// Add 6 days to reach the last day of the current week
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);
// End date for the week
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();
```