# Get Week Dates From Monday to Friday from a Given Date

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I want to get the Week Dates from Monday to Friday From a Given Date.

Suppose if the Given Date is 6-2-2013

I want the result :

```
Monday    4-2-2013
Tuesday   5-2-2013
Wednesday 6-2-2013
Thursday  7-2-2013
Friday    8-2-2013
```

or Even i have the Week no as 6 ...How can i achieve the About result

I get the Week no from the Below Code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);

int weekNo = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/8652514/1777090 . That might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 6-2-2013:

```
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 1, 6);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONDAY - c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
        while(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            if (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 2013) {
                System.out.printf("%-10tA%10s%n", c.getTime(), df.format(c.getTime()));
            }
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
prints

    Monday      4-2-2013
    Tuesday     5-2-2013
    Wednesday   6-2-2013
    Thursday    7-2-2013
    Friday      8-2-2013
from week 6 of 2013:

    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 6 - 1);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONDAY - c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
        while(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            if (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 2013) {
                System.out.printf("%-10tA%10s%n", c.getTime(), df.format(c.getTime()));
            }
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
```

prints

```
Monday      4-2-2013
Tuesday     5-2-2013
Wednesday   6-2-2013
Thursday    7-2-2013
Friday      8-2-2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...I have edited and added more changes to Achintya Jha Code...Works Fine
Thanks to Achintya Jha

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);

int weekNo = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

//Set the Week No
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNo);

c.clear();

//Set the Week Year and the Week No
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNo);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);


SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy"); // PST`
//Get Week Start Date 
Date startDate = c.getTime();
//Now it will be sunday so add plus one so now it becomes Monday
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //From Monday to Friday Dates will be Printed
    System.out.println(formatter.format(c.getTime()));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getWeekOfDates(2013, 2, 11);

}

private static void getWeekOfDates(int year, int month, int day) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    int weekOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekOfMonth);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd-MM-yyyy");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

}
```

Try this: I edited as your requirement.

Output:

```
Mon 11-03-2013
Tue 12-03-2013
Wed 13-03-2013
Thu 14-03-2013
Fri 15-03-2013
```

Comment: I will try this now...Thks

Comment: Suppose my given date is 14/2...it even adds the next week Dates(ie..)next week monday and tuesday too...i think i must change your code slightly...Thnks

Comment: @sdg I edited my code as your requirement.

Comment: Yeah thks..But if i give the Date as 14/2..?????? result is Different

Comment: @sdg 14 is thursday so you want to print thursday and friday only?

Comment: Its user choice they can choose any date in a week...Suppose they choose thursday that week from monday to friday to be printed..like 11/2,12/2,13/2,14/2,15/2

Comment: @sdg did you figure out a working solution? Could you please share it so that it helps others who have a similar problem? Thank you.